# SSH over AnyDesk?

Tags: ssh, git, tunnel, gitlab, anydesk

SSH traffic is blocked by my ISP's adult filter but AnyDesk (and maybe TeamViewer) are allowed. I'm on Windows and need to be able to work on some GitLab project over SSH, like e.g.: `git clone git@gitlab.com:user/project.git` with Git BASH and/or GIT GUI.

Is there a way to tunnel SSH through AnyDesk/TeamViewer somehow? Preferably without relying on others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is possible:

```
                       ||
|-----|   SSH within   ||   |-------|           |--------|
| YOU |<===AnyDesk=========>| OTHER |<---SSH--->| GITLAB |
|-----|    Tunnel      ||   |-------|           |--------| 
                ISP    ||
              Blockade ||
```

This assumes that YOU are behind the SSH blocking ISP Blockade, but can connect via AnyDesk to OTHER (outside of that ISP Blockade).

Then you can go to "Setup TCP tunneling" and setup a tunnel (NOT reverse tunnel) with a local port of (say) 6789, remote host gitlab.com and remote port 22 (SSH port).  Once you connect with that tunnel you can use your port 6789 to access gitlab.com:22, e.g. `git clone ssh://git@127.0.0.1:6789/gitlab-org/gitlab` instead of `git clone git@gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab`.

Answer (score 2):

A better option might be to not use SSH and use HTTPS instead. Gitlab includes both options to clone a repo. On the main page, click on the `SSH` dropdown (see image below) and select HTTPS. Then copy the URL and do `git clone <copied-url>`

[image: gitlab Repo page]

Comment: http is also blocked generally. only a couple of whitelisted websites are allowed.

Comment: Your *ISP* only allows a couple of whitelisted websites? Are you in a ridiculously authoritarian country? Can you get another ISP?

Comment: It is a sort of "Internet access for kids" which allows only Gmail usage. It's OK.